C# Entity Framework & object patterns
I have a program that has a number of objects (say 200).
In addition, I have Entity Framework which declares a DbSet for each of these.
The objects are similar (but not identical). I feel like a factory pattern would be worthwhile here to build the objects as well as the DbContext dynamically.
Is it possible to dynamically build a DbContext, aligned with an object factory?
Bonus: can the objects be defined in a tabular or text data rather than code? (easier to share a .csv file with business than a few hundred lines of c#)
namespace nameObjectA
{
    public class Object A
    {
        public Prop1
        public Prop2
        ...
    }
}


namespace nameObjectZ
{
    public class Object Z
    {
        public Prop1
        public Prop2
        ...
    }
}


namespace DatabaseOps
{
    public class OpsContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ObjectA> ObjectsA { get; set }
        // ...
        public DbSet<ObjectZ> ObjectsZ { get; set }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().Property(x => x.Prop1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().Property(x => x.Prop2);
            // ...
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectZ>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectZ>().Property(x => x.Prop1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectZ>().Property(x => x.Prop2);
        }
    }
}


It is possible with a source generator.

Look at T4 templates for this kind of stuff.

Fluent-api can be used for configuring these similar entities.
First create an interface that has these same properties:
public interface IFooInterface
{
  string FooProperty { get; set; }
  ...
}

Then create an extension class for EntityTypeBuilder and create a static method like following:
public static class FooEntityTypeBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureByConvention(this EntityTypeBuilder b)
    {
        b.TryConfigureFooCommonFields();
    }

    public static void TryConfigureFooCommonFields(this EntityTypeBuilder b)
    {
        if (b.Metadata.ClrType.IsAssignableTo<IFooInterface>())
        {
            b.Property(nameof(IFooInterface.FooProperty))
                .HasMaxLength(FooConstant.BarLength)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(IFooInterface.FooProperty));
            ...
        }
    }
}

Then configure your entities using Fluent-api :

public class FooConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {        
        builder.ConfigureByConvention();
        ....
        // configure not common properties.
    }
}

DbContext:
public class FooDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ObjectA> ObjectsA { get; set }
    // ...
    public DbSet<ObjectZ> ObjectsZ { get; set }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder); 
builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(FooDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}

